# Do I have to fix audit issues of the latest nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, yarnpkg

I am trying to use nuxt for my app, but when I run "yarn audit", there are some audit issues which are dependencies of nuxt.

Do I have to fix these audit issues? And if I have to, how can I fix it?

I am using nuxt 2.15.7 and I added the latest `css-what` but it didn't changed.

```
yarn audit v1.22.10
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ moderate      │ Regular expression denial of service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ glob-parent                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=5.1.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ nuxt                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ nuxt > @nuxt/builder > @nuxt/webpack > webpack > watchpack > │
│               │ watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar > glob-parent                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1751                        │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ moderate      │ Regular expression denial of service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ glob-parent                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=5.1.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ nuxt                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ nuxt > @nuxt/webpack > webpack > watchpack >                 │
│               │ watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar > glob-parent                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1751                        │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ high          │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ css-what                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=5.0.1                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ nuxt                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ nuxt > @nuxt/builder > @nuxt/webpack > cssnano >             │
│               │ cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo > css-select >  │
│               │ css-what                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1754                        │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ high          │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ css-what                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=5.0.1                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ nuxt                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ nuxt > @nuxt/webpack > cssnano > cssnano-preset-default >    │
│               │ postcss-svgo > svgo > css-select > css-what                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1754                        │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ high          │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ css-what                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=5.0.1                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ nuxt                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ nuxt > @nuxt/builder > @nuxt/webpack >                       │
│               │ optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin > cssnano >               │
│               │ cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo > css-select >  │
│               │ css-what                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1754                        │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ high          │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ css-what                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=5.0.1                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ nuxt                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ nuxt > @nuxt/webpack > optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin >  │
│               │ cssnano > cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo >     │
│               │ css-select > css-what                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1754                        │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
6 vulnerabilities found - Packages audited: 1199
Severity: 2 Moderate | 4 High
Done in 1.67s.
```

```
$yarn list --pattern css-what
yarn list v1.22.10
├─ css-what@5.0.1
└─ svgo@1.3.2
   └─ css-what@3.4.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the severity is `moderate/high` and it's a `Denial of Service`, you don't really have to worry about it. In case of big huge `critical` one, the Internet, Github and your colleagues will alert you.

As of fixing it, there is no `yarn audit fix` as in `npm`, but we can use `npm` just to fix those or do fix those manually with Yarn, here is a nice article on how to achieve this: https://javascriptbit.com/yarn-audit-fix-security-issues/